# Chart.JS is only updated once

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I use Chart.JS to display some values ​​from a MySQL database. So far I have just reloaded the whole page to display new data. You can do it like that, but it's not nice.

So I tried the update function of Chart.JS.

During the first run after reloading via the browser, the point in Chart 1 (MP1chart) still changes with it. In all further runs, only the randomly generated points in Chart 2 (MP2chart) jump wildly back and forth. But nothing moves in chart 1 until I reload the whole page.

I've read some forum posts and tried various solutions. But none of them brought the desired success.

I suspect that it is related to the fact that PHP is the language on the server side, so it is only executed once and then never again until the whole page is reloaded? Whereas the Javascript points are updated on the client side.

But as hard as I've tried in the last few hours, I don't get my new data from the PHP script (loads data from MySQL database) into the Chart.JS diagram more than once via the update function.

Can someone at least show me the way to the solution. A link and a few keywords that I do not recognize myself at the moment will surely help me to find the solution for myself.

Sorry if my english is not perfect. It's not my native language, but I try my best.

**The PHP + Javascript for Update Chart.JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 0;
    
          function re_load(x) {
    
    
<?php           
$phpnumber = rand(1900, 1960);
$phpnumber = $phpnumber / 1000;

echo 'var javanumber = ' .$phpnumber. ';';

?>

    
   
    
    MP1chart.data.datasets[3].data[5] = javanumber;
    MP2chart.data.datasets[3].data[2] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    MP2chart.data.datasets[3].data[3] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    
    window.MP1chart.update();
    window.MP2chart.update();
    
    
           setTimeout("re_load(x+1)",100);
    
      }
      setTimeout("re_load(x+1)",100);
    </script>
```

Comment: you need ajax call to retrieve data from your server.

Comment: Even if my Ajax knowledge is currently still very expandable, but I will teach myself that as an autodidact :)

This script only runs on the intranet and only for me and my colleagues, so I can do some learning by doing.

Thank you.